# NGINX configuration: Angular SPA in root and Slim REST API in subfolder

Tags: angularjs, nginx, slim

I can't get it to work!

```
location ~ ^/(api) {
    #api requests
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.php;
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
} 
location / {
    #angular app
    try_files $uri /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

I can load the base api path, ie `https://test.com/api` and it returns the 404 json response as expected, since accessing the root of the api is illegal.

however, trying to run any route in the api, such as `https://test.com/api/v1/authenticate` and it ends up being passed to the front end application in the second location block!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some experimentation, i determined that having the api in a subdirectory was causing the problem. i moved the api's `index.php` from `/api/index.php` to  to the root folder (`/`) and renamed it api.php

then by changing my slim app group from `/v1` to `/api/v1` the following nginx configuration now works correctly:

```
location ~ ^/api {
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /api.php?$query_string;
}

location / {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri /index.html?$query_string;
}
```